# Questions regarding the category of $R$-algebras

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, category-theory

Let $R$ be any commutative ring with $1$. I'm having some doubts regarding $R$-Alg, the category of $R$-algebras, which is the co-slice category under $R$ in the category of commutative rings.

(1)[Is $R$ initial in the category of $R$-algebras?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544382/is-r-initial-in-the-category-of-r-algebras). I am not convinced by the argument presented in the link regarding the initial object property of $R$.  Suppose I take some ring homomorphism $f: R \rightarrow A$. Clearly $f(r)=r.f(1_{R})=r.1_{A}\;.$ Now why can't we have several possible action of $r$ on $1_{A}$, leading to several possible maps. I mean if we consider $R=\mathbb{Z}$ then $f(n)=n.1_{A}$, which is the $n$- times addition of $1_{A}$, therefore the action is uniquely determined and we get the unique $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra map. But it is not clear to me for general $R$.

(2) More generally, is it abelian category? or rather a Grothendieck category like $R$-Mod.

(3) What kind of inclusion is $R\hbox{-}Alg \rightarrow Comrings$? It seems to be a full subcategory. Is there any left or right adjoint to this inclusion?

thanks in advance!

Comment: An $R$-algebra is in effect a ring homomorphism from $R$ to a ring $A$. That homomorphism is the unique algebra map from $R$ to $A$.

Comment: It's not an Abelian category. The initial and terminal objects are not isomorphic.

Comment: It's not a full subcategory in general. Consider a ring with a nontrivial automorphism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the questions were answered in the comments. Like any forgetful functor from a co-slice category, that from algebras to ring preserves limits but not, generally, colimits-for the latter, just note that tensoring over $R$ is not the same as tensoring over $\mathbb Z$. Thus there can’t be a right adjoint, but there is a left adjoint, given by $A\mapsto R\otimes_{\mathbb Z} A$, with the algebra structure all in the left side of the tensor.